# Display data from the documents folder into UITableView and go to the selection in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, save

I'm making an app that allows the user to create files (html) and edit / view them. The files are save in the Documents folder of the app. I'd like to know if there is any good way to display all the files and folders in a UITableView.

Also how would you pass on the user's selection to the text view to be read? I know it would some how get the row id and pass on the name were the function could load the file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *currentDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:NULL];
```

will give you an array of the file names as NSString in the documents directory, then you just use it as your data for the table view. when a file is selected, you can use `NSMutableData`'s `initWithContentsOfFile` method with the path as the variable to get a `NSMutableData` object to pass to your editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the cell textLabels, then passing the string is a no-brainer.  In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, do something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//alloc and init view with custom init method that accepts NSString* argument  
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:"];
NSString*pathToPass = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text]; //pass this.

}
```

Comment: Could you please include going into dictionaries (cd). If your do that you can get your check :D